# Why is text typed into other cells appearing in a cell with no formulas in a workbook with no macros?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have a workbook with a few sheets of data, one PowerQuery, a few pivot tables.

On one of the sheets, when I type into some cells at the top of the workbook, whatever I type is repeated in cell B3. It appears large at first, then the text shown in B3 compresses as I type longer sentences.

There are no formulas in B3. There are no macros in the workbook. There is no code acting on the workbook in any way.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before? Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Please keep an eye on the formula bar. I type something in cell B3 then delete it. Then I type in other cells but the typed data is repeated in or over cell B3

[image]

EDIT: I've since learned that whatever I type in ANY cell in any sheet in the workbook is repeated in this way in/over cell B3 on every sheet. This includes newly created sheets.

Comment: try to repro the problem in another file. If you can't, there's probably some kind of corruption in the original file. If you CAN repro, please use a file sharing service to share a copy. (sanitize the data!!)

Comment: I think this should be a problem with the file itself, try refreshing the PivotTable, and if your situation allows, I suggest you re-acquire the PivotTable.

Comment: Is there any conditional formatting?

Comment: There was no conditional formatting and I the problem was not localised to a pivot table. Problem was also not reproducible the next day. Is it good form to delete this qn now? I doubt there would ever be an answer tbh.

Comment: @FlexYourData ,, it's quit interesting,, please share the Workbook with us & let it examine since what happens is unusual !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha, unfortunately this workbook is from a company I am no longer working with. I will try to replicate the issue and report back here if I'm able.

Comment: @FlexYourData ,,, okay no issue,,, since the issue is quite different/uncommon ,,, so the would be just examine the WB,,, what is behind !!

Comment: Sir may I know what was the solution and what was the cause of the problem here. Why was it happening? Have you got it resolved if yes then please can you share in answers pleasex

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I'm afraid I never found a solution, nor a cause to this problem. I haven't experienced it since, so I assume that whatever the problem was has since been solved in an Excel update. If I see it again, I'll be sure to add context to this post.

Comment: Thank you very much @FlexYourData Sir!